# hotfile account checker

Tags: html, delphi, url

i wanna make hotfile account checker

inorder to start working ,i want to know how to login 
i tried this

> http://www.hotfile.com/login.php?user=myusername&pass=mypassword

but it saying Bad username/password combination. :( even if i entred correct login data

can any one help me please thanks in advance

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Raffael said, you have to use post instead of get, also there's hidden field called: `returnto`, I usually do that with help of indy idHttp component as following:

```
var
 Sl :  TStringList;
begin
  Sl := TStringList.Create;
  Sl.Add('user=myuser');
  Sl.Add('pass=mypassword');
  sl.Add('returnto=/');

  Memo1.Text :=  IdHTTP1.Post('http://www.hotfile.com/login.php',Sl);

  FreeAndNil(sl);
end;
```

also be sure to make idHttp property `HandleRedirects = True`

Comment: thanks for reply sir 
i want to create my checker using wininet ,so i want to use internetopenurl and readfile ,in that sense ,what my url input can be 
like http://www.hotfile.com/login.php&user=+edit1.text&pass=+edit2.text
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Checking the source of hotfile.com website you can see, that the login form is defined like this:

```
<form action="/login.php" method="post">
```

So to write an account checker you need to "post" to the login.php url. What you did is a "get" request.

Raffael

Comment: thanks for reply mate ,
but i am noob in http can u give me correct link 
thanks in advance